# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char' C#

Tags: c#

i'm pretty new to coding so i'm a bit baffled.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char varcommand;
            Console.WriteLine("Input a command");

            varcommand = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            if (
            varcommand = ("farm"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start farming run timer.");

        }
    }
}
```

Trying to take an input  e.g: "farm" and start a timer from it. dont understand why it isnt already converted to char. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, this is C#, not C++ - also, `char` is a single character, not a string - lastly, you want to use `==` to compare, not `=`.

Comment: and there shouldn't be a semicolon immediately after `if (condition)`.

Comment: ...and you can't compare a `char` to a `char*` ("farm").

Comment: as you can tell, im pretty new, i didnt even know which language this was haha. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: thanks for editing my tags and such people!

Answer (score 1):

Cool, something I'm finally qualified to answer.  Like the comment above said, any time you have multiple characters together it's a string.  "Farm" is a string.  If it was just a single letter such as "x", then it would be a char.

Try this...

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a command");
varCommand = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
if(varCommand == "farm")
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Press start to enter farming run timer.");
    }
```